# Bokeh BoxPlot > KeyError: 'the label [SomeCategory] is not in the [index]'

Tags: python-3.x

I'm attempting to create a BoxPlot using Bokeh. When I get to the section where I need to identify outliers, it fails if a given category has no outliers.

If I remove the "problem" category, the BoxPlot executes properly. it's only when I attempt to create this BoxPlot with a category that has no outliers it fails.

Any instruction on how to remedy this?

The failure occurs at the commented section "Prepare outlier data for plotting [...]"

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import math

from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
from bokeh.models import NumeralTickFormatter

# Create time stamps to allow for figure to display span in title
today  = datetime.date.today()
delta1 = datetime.timedelta(days=7)
delta2 = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
start  = str(today - delta1)
end    = str(today - delta2)

#Identify location of prices
itemloc = 'Everywhere'

df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\me\prices.xlsx')

# Create a list from the dataframe that identifies distinct categories for the separate box plots
cats = df['subcategory_desc'].unique().tolist()

# Find the quartiles and IQR for each category
groups = df.groupby('subcategory_desc', sort=False)
q1 = groups.quantile(q=0.25)
q2 = groups.quantile(q=0.5)
q3 = groups.quantile(q=0.75)
iqr = q3 - q1
upper = q3 + 1.5*iqr
lower = q1 - 1.5*iqr

# Find the outliers for each category
def outliers(group):
    cat = group.name
    return group[(group.price > upper.loc[cat][0]) | (group.price < lower.loc[cat][0])]['price']
out = groups.apply(outliers).dropna()

# Prepare outlier data for plotting, we need coordinates for every outlier.
outx = []
outy = []
for cat in cats:
    # only add outliers if they exist
    if not out.loc[cat].empty:
        for value in out[cat]:
            outx.append(cat)
            outy.append(value)
```

I expect that the Box-and-whisker portion of categories with no outliers merely show up without the outlier dots.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the code from official documentation, https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/boxplot.html?

```
# prepare outlier data for plotting, we need coordinates for every outlier.
if not out.empty:
    outx = []
    outy = []
    for keys in out.index:
        outx.append(keys[0])
        outy.append(out.loc[keys[0]].loc[keys[1]])
```